# SQLite for JSON

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic2/Angular2.

I am looking to store data on the users device/browser.  I could use Local Storage, but have read it's not reliable.

SQLite is reliable, but is SQL and not JSON. Also, I think it won't work in a browser because it requires a Cordova plugin.

Question

Is there a way to store JSON reliably locally accessible from a devise and a browser?

Thanks

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [Ionic Storage](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/).

In the case of browser it will pick the browser storage available.
If you prefer `sqlite` you have to install:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save
```

The API takes key-value pairs to read/write to db.
So storing json data is possible.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try.